# adding <div> tag and <video> tag inside joomla 2.5.7 articles

Tags: html, joomla

I am unable to add div and video tags inside joomla 2.5.7 articles as when i am adding the div but content is not showing on live.

```
<div class="rightside">
<div>
<video width="900" height="550">
<source src="http://eb5mg.com/video/1.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</source>
<source src="http://eb5mg.com/video/eb5.ogg" type="video/ogg">
</source>
</video>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below code

```
<div class="rightside">
<div>
    <video width="900" height="550">
      <source src="http://eb5mg.com/video/1.mp4" type="video/mp4">
      <source src="http://eb5mg.com/video/eb5.ogg" type="video/ogg">
    Your browser does not support the video tag.
    </video>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: there wasn't any error instead the article area just goes WHITE.

Comment: i have changed my editor to CodeMirror but still it didn't worked

Comment: If you are getting a white screen turn your error reporting to maximum. THen you will get the error message. Or look in your source or apache error log.

Answer (score 0):

I see this is an old topic but I went though this same problem. It has everything to do with Joomla and for me it came from two separate sources.

First there is a html word filter which is part of the global configuration which on defualt uses a black list to strip out many tags. I set the publisher and super users Filter Type to No Filtering but depending on your users and security needs you might want to be more strict (say like expand on the black list and only allow super user to have no filter).

Then is the wyswyg editor you are using for your articles. It also may be text filtering your html, TinyMCE which was my defaut editor also has options for stripping out code which you can adjust but after playing with it for a while I changed my users profile text editor to none.

After that my video tags worked and I imagine your div tags will work too.